# Objection Detection not detecting GPU with Tensorflow GPU Image

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I am a little stuck on my new adventures with machine learning.

I've been folloing a uDemy course where the instructure is running directly on their machine, however, I'm doing my best to run it all via Docker.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.1.1-gpu

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y espeak ffmpeg libespeak1 alsa-base alsa-utils protobuf-compiler python-pil python-lxml python-tk
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN python3 -m pip install pandas
RUN python3 -m pip install pillow

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/models/research

RUN protoc object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/argmax_matcher.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/bipartite_matcher.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/box_coder.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/box_predictor.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/calibration.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/center_net.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/eval.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/faster_rcnn.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/faster_rcnn_box_coder.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/flexible_grid_anchor_generator.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/fpn.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/graph_rewriter.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/grid_anchor_generator.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/hyperparams.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/image_resizer.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/input_reader.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/keypoint_box_coder.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/losses.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/matcher.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/mean_stddev_box_coder.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/model.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/multiscale_anchor_generator.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/optimizer.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/pipeline.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/post_processing.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/preprocessor.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/region_similarity_calculator.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/square_box_coder.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/ssd.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/ssd_anchor_generator.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/string_int_label_map.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/target_assigner.proto --python_out=.
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/train.proto --python_out=.

RUN cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
RUN python3 -m pip install .

WORKDIR /app

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8 

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/python3"]
```

I'm running this through VS Codes' Remote Container: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#:~:text=The%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%20Remote,Studio%20Code's%20full%20feature%20set](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#:%7E:text=The%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%20Remote,Studio%20Code%27s%20full%20feature%20set)

devcontainer.json:

```json
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the README at:
// https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.194.0/containers/docker-existing-dockerfile
{
    "name": "Existing Dockerfile",

    // Sets the run context to one level up instead of the .devcontainer folder.
    "context": "..",

    // Update the 'dockerFile' property if you aren't using the standard 'Dockerfile' filename.
    "dockerFile": "../Dockerfile",

    // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
    "settings": {},
    
    // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
    "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python",
        "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
        "streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker",
        "editorconfig.editorconfig"
    ],

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // "forwardPorts": [],

    // Uncomment the next line to run commands after the container is created - for example installing curl.
    // "postCreateCommand": "apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl",

    // Uncomment when using a ptrace-based debugger like C++, Go, and Rust
    // "runArgs": [ "--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE", "--security-opt", "seccomp=unconfined" ],
    "runArgs": ["--gpus", "all", "--device=/dev/snd:/dev/snd"]

    // Uncomment to use the Docker CLI from inside the container. See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/samples/docker-from-docker.
    // "mounts": [ "source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock,type=bind" ],

    // Uncomment to connect as a non-root user if you've added one. See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
    // "remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

Once I am in the container, if I run `nvidia-smi`, I get the following output which tells me it sees my GPU.

```
Tue Oct 26 19:55:24 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.91.03    Driver Version: 460.91.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 207...  Off  | 00000000:26:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   45C    P8     4W / 215W |     37MiB /  7974MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, when I go to call follow the training and evaluating sets in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_training_and_evaluation.md#local I get the following:

```
Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
2021-10-26 19:05:23.611986: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an outdated version of TensorFlow... which does not support CUDA 11.02

"TensorFlow supports CUDA® 11.2 (TensorFlow >= 2.5.0)" as seen here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements

Replaced image version with latest and all is working as expected it seems, derp.